# SQL Query generator, round 2

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, sql

> This is the second round of reviews. The first round can be found [in this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172713/sql-query-generator).

This is a project I have been working on. This is one of my first experiences with Python and OOP as a whole. I have written a GUI that handles the inputs for these classes, but I will ask for a separate review for that, since the question would be rather bulky when including both.

The goal of this program is to create standard SQL (SQL server) queries for everyday use. The rationale behind this is that we regularly need similar queries, and would like to prevent common mistakes in them. The focus on this question is on the Python code however.

The information about the tables and their relation to each-other is provided by a JSON file, of which I have attached a mock-up version.

The code consists of three parts:

- A universe class which handles the JSON file and creates the context of the tables.
- A query class, which handles the specifications of which tables to include, which columns to take, how to join each table and optional where statements.
- A PyQT GUI that handles the inputs. **This is excluded in this post and will be posted separately for another review.** It can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/JarkoDubbeldam/SQL-builder/blob/master/ui.py)

The JSON:

```
{
  "graph": {
    "table1": {
      "tag": ["table1"],
      "DBHandle": ["tables.table1"],
      "Priority": [1],
      "Columns": ["a", "b", "c"],
      "Joins": {
        "table2": ["on table2.a = table1.a", "inner"],
        "table3": ["on table1.c = table3.c", "inner"]

      }
    },
    "table2": {
      "tag": ["table2"],
      "DBHandle": ["tables.table2"],
      "Priority": [2],
      "Columns": ["a", "d", "e"],
      "Joins": {
        "table3": ["on table2.d=table3.d and table2.e = table3.e", "inner"]
      }
    },
    "table3": {
      "tag": ["table3"],
      "DBHandle": ["tables.table3"],
      "Priority": [4],
      "Columns": ["c", "d", "e"],
      "Joins": []
    }
  },
  "presets": {
    "non empty b": {
      "table": ["table1"],
      "where": ["table1.b is not null"]
    }
  }
}
```

The reviewed Python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Aug  3 14:33:44 2017

@author: jdubbeldam
"""
from json import loads

class Universe:
    """
    The Universe is a context for the Query class. It contains the information
    of the available Database tables and their relation to eachother. This
    information is stored in a JSON file.
    """

    def __init__(self, filename):
        """
        Reads the JSON and separates the information in a presets dictionary and
        a graph dictionary. The latter contains the information of the nodes in
        the universe/graph, including relational information.
        """
        with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
            self.json = loads(str(file.read()))
        self.presets = self.json['presets']
        self.json = self.json['graph']
        self.tables = self.json.keys()
        self.connections = self.get_edges()

    def get_edges(self):
        """
        Creates a dictionary with for each node a list of nodes that join on
        that node.
        """

        edges = {}
        for table in self.tables:
            edges[table] = []
            try:
                edges[table] += [connected_tables
                                 for connected_tables in self.json[table]['Joins']]
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        for node in edges:
            for connected_node in edges[node]:
                if node not in edges[connected_node]:
                    edges[connected_node].append(node)
        return edges

    def shortest_path(self, start, end, path_argument=None):
        """
        Calculates the shortest path in a graph, using the dictionary created
        in getEgdes. Adapted from https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/.
        """
        if path_argument is None:
            old_path = []
        else:
            old_path = path_argument
        path = old_path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return path
        if start not in self.connections:
            return None
        shortest = None
        for node in self.connections[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpath = self.shortest_path(node, end, path)
                if newpath:
                    if not shortest or len(newpath) < len(shortest):
                        shortest = newpath
        return shortest

    def join_paths(self, nodes):
        """
        Extension of shortest_path to work with multiple nodes to be connected.
        The nodes are sorted based on the priority, which is taken from the JSON.
        shortest_path is called on the first two nodes, then iteratively on each
        additional node and one of the existing nodes returned by shortest_path,
        selecting the one that takes the fewest steps.
        """
        sorted_nodes = sorted([[self.json[node]['Priority'][0], node] for node in nodes])
        paths = []

        paths.append(self.shortest_path(sorted_nodes[0][1], sorted_nodes[1][1]))
        for next_node_index in range(len(sorted_nodes) - 2):
            shortest = None
            flat_paths = [item for sublist in paths for item in sublist]
            old_path = len(flat_paths)
            for connected_path in flat_paths:
                newpath = self.shortest_path(connected_path,
                                             sorted_nodes[next_node_index+2][1],
                                             flat_paths)
                if newpath:
                    if not shortest or len(newpath[old_path:]) < len(shortest):
                        shortest = newpath[old_path:]
            paths.append(shortest)
        return paths


class Query:
    """
    Query contains the functions that allow us to build an SQL query based on
    a universe object. It maintains lists with the names of activated tables
    and, if applicable, which of their columns in a dictionary. Implicit tables
    are tables that are called, only to bridge joins from one table to another.
    Since they are not explicitly called, we don't want their columns in the query.
    how_to_join is a dictionary that allows setting joins (left, right, inner, full)
    other than the defaults imported from the JSON.
    """
    core = 'select\n\n{columns}\n\nfrom {joins}\n\n where {where}'

    def __init__(self, universum):

        self.graph = universum
        self.active_tables = []
        self.active_columns = {}
        self.implicit_tables = []
        self.join_strings = {}
        for i in self.graph.tables:
            self.join_strings[i] = self.graph.json[i]['Joins']
        self.how_to_join = {}
        self.where = []

    def add_tables(self, tablename):
        """
        Sets given tablename to active. GUI ensures that only valid names
        will be given.
        """
        if tablename not in self.active_tables:
            self.active_tables.append(tablename)
            self.active_columns[tablename] = []

    def add_columns(self, table, column):
        """
        Sets given columnname from table to active. GUI ensures that only valid names
        will be given.
        """
        if column not in self.active_columns[table]:
            self.active_columns[table].append(column)

    def add_where(self, string):
        """
        Adds any string to a list to be input as where statement. This could be
        vulnerable for SQL injection, but the scope of this project is in-house
        usage, and the generated SQL query isn't directly passed to the server.
        """
        self.where.append(string)


    def find_joins(self):
        """
        Calls the join_paths function from Universe class. Figures out which joins
        are needed and which tables need to be implicitly added. Returns a list
        of tuples with tablenames to be joined.
        """
        tags = [self.graph.json[table]['tag'][0]
                for table in self.active_tables]
        join_paths = self.graph.join_paths(tags)
        join_sets = [(table1, table2)
                     for join_edge in join_paths
                     for table1, table2 in zip(join_edge[:-1], join_edge[1:])]
        for sublist in join_paths:
            for item in sublist:
                if item not in self.active_tables:
                    self.add_tables(item)
                    self.implicit_tables.append(item)
        return join_sets

    def generate_join_statement(self, table_tuple):
        """
        Creates the join statement for a given tuple of tablenames. The second
        entry in the tuple is always the table that is joined. Since the string
        is stored in a dictionary with one specific combination of the two table
        names, the try statement checks which way around it needs to be. how contains
        the default way to join. Unless otherwise specified, this is used to generate
        the join string.
        """
        added_table = table_tuple[1]
        try:
            on_string, how = self.graph.json[table_tuple[0]]['Joins'][table_tuple[1]]
        except TypeError:
            table_tuple = (table_tuple[1], table_tuple[0])
            on_string, how = self.graph.json[table_tuple[0]]['Joins'][table_tuple[1]]


        if table_tuple not in self.how_to_join:
            self.how_to_join[table_tuple] = how

        join_string = (self.how_to_join[table_tuple]
                       + ' join '
                       + self.graph.json[added_table]['DBHandle'][0]
                       + ' '
                       +  self.graph.json[added_table]['tag'][0]
                       + '\n')
        return join_string + on_string

    def generate_select_statement(self, table):
        """
        Creates the column specification. If no columns of an active table are
        specified, it assumes all the columns are wanted.
        """
        if not self.active_columns[table]:
            self.active_columns[table] = ['*']
        return ',\n'.join([(self.graph.json[table]['tag'][0]
                            + '.'
                            + i)
                           for i in self.active_columns[table]])


    def compile_query(self):
        """
        Handles compilation of the query. If there are more than one activated
        table, joins need to be handled. First the required joins are found, then
        the strings that handle this are generated. The column statement is created.
        If there is no where statement specified, '1=1' is added. The relevent
        statements are added into the core query and returned.
        """
        if len(self.active_tables) == 1:
            base_table = self.active_tables[0]
            join_statement = []
        else:
            joins = self.find_joins()
            base_table = joins[0][0]
            join_statement = [self.generate_join_statement(i) for i in joins]
        join_statement = ([self.graph.json[base_table]['DBHandle'][0]
                           + ' '
                           + self.graph.json[base_table]['tag'][0]]
                          + join_statement)
        completed_join_statement = '\n\n'.join(join_statement)


        column_statement = [self.generate_select_statement(table)
                            for table in self.active_tables
                            if table not in self.implicit_tables]



        completed_column_statement = ',\n'.join(column_statement)


        if self.where:
            where_statement = '\nand '.join(self.where)
        else:
            where_statement = '1 = 1'

        query = Query.core.replace('{columns}', completed_column_statement)
        query = query.replace('{joins}', completed_join_statement)
        query = query.replace('{where}', where_statement)

        return query


if __name__ == "__main__":
    graph = Universe('example.JSON')
    query = Query(graph)
    query.addTables('table1')
    query.addTables('table2')
    query.addTables('table3')
    print(query.compileQuery())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been refactoring this code myself as well in the meanwhile, so I thought I'd post some of the insights I have gained myself.

### Class inheritance

Instead of passing a `Universe` instance when creating a `Query`, by making `Query` a subclass of `Universe`, I was able to reduce the amount of information that was stored in both classes. This makes accessing the attributes and methods of `Universe` in `Query`'s methods shorter as well.

### `Query.join_strings` does nothing

```
    self.join_strings = {}
    for i in self.graph.tables:
        self.join_strings[i] = self.graph.json[i]['Joins']
```

`self.join_strings` is defined, but used nowhere else. Also the use of `i` is bad (was an oversight).

### Indirectly still iterating over `.keys()`

```
    self.json = self.json['graph']
    self.tables = self.json.keys()
```

in `Universe.__init__()` stores the keys (tablenames). This is only used to iterate later:

```
    edges = {}
    for table in self.tables:
        edges[table] = []
        try:
            edges[table] += [connected_tables
                             for connected_tables in self.json[table]['Joins']]
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

We might as well have iterated over `self.json`. However, for naming purposes, I prefer the following:

```
    self.tables = self.json['graph']
```

Since that improves the naming, and removes the need to keep the `json` attribute around. So we can turn that into a regular variable without the `self`.

### Expand the `add_*` methods to also allow for removing of that item.

This is mostly relevant with the GUI in mind. It contained a bit of a workaround to be able to remove tables and columns from the Query.

So I added an argument to the `add_*` methods to be able to set to remove instead.

```
def add_tables(self, tablename, add_or_remove=True):
    """
    Toggles active setting of given tablename. GUI ensures that only valid names
    will be given.
    """
    if add_or_remove:
        if tablename not in self.active_tables:
            self.active_tables.append(tablename)
            self.active_columns[tablename] = []
    else:
        self.active_tables.remove(tablename)
```

Comment: So, without looking at your code, what does `add_or_remove = True` mean? Does it add or remove? I would make it `remove=False`, or vastly preferred if possible, just have a `remove` method...

Comment: @Graipher good point. Turning it into a separate method is definitely possible. It just means that I move the `if` statement to the GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Since I noticed `if __name__ == "__main__":`, I assume you are executing the python file from commandline. If so, you could also add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the very top of your file, and make the file executable (`chmod a+x`) so that you can simply execute with `./filename.py` in *nix cli.

---

When you define `Query.core` query, you should not hardbind this. It would not be extensible in current scenario; in the sense that if you wish to provide `INSERT` or `DELETE` clauses to your generator.

Comment: `object` is not needed anymore as a base class in Python 3 (which this question is tagged with) as it is implied for any class (pretty much like you don't specify `metaclass=type` either).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the method names `query.method_name()` were misspelled as `object.methodName()`.  That is they were camelCase syntax, so the example above will not run.  After changing those to PEP8 format `object.add_tables()` syntax, the application runs.

```
def main():
    """
    Creates an example query
    """
    file = 'example.JSON'
    query = Query(file)
    query.add_tables('table1')
    query.add_tables('table2')
    query.add_tables('table3')
    print(query.compile_query())
```

I need more information on the `universe.uni` initialization file in order to flesh out this application completely and get it working.